# machine precision

Tags: c++, c, precision, interpolation

I wonder if there is something like eps to represent the value of machine precision in C++? Can I use it as the smallest positive number that a double can represent? Is it possible to use 1.0/eps as the max positive number that a double can represent? Where can I find eps in both C++ and C standard libraries?

Thanks and regards!

---

UPDATE:

For my purpose, I would like to compute a weight as reciprocal of a distance for something like inverse distance weighting interpolation (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting).

```
double wgt = 0, wgt_tmp, result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < num; i++)
{
   wgt_tmp = 1.0/dist[i];
   wgt += wgt_tmp;
   result += wgt_tmp * values[i];
}
results /= wgt;
```

However the distance can be 0 and I need to make the weight suitable for computation. If there is only one distance dist[i] is 0, I would like its corresponding value values[i] to be dominant. If there are several distances are 0, I would like to have their values to contribute equally to the result. Any idea how to implement it?

Comment: Would you actually want to use the largest double precision number for the weight? There might be problems, especially if the distance is 0 for more than one value of i. The maximum value of a double is about 10^308. It might be better to set wgt_tmp to something like 10^150 when distance==0, which (so long as the other weights are much smaller than this) will have the effect of taking an unweighted mean over all values where distance==0, when such values exist, or a weighted mean over all values when all distances are nonzero.

Comment: Thanks Chris. They are good suggestions. when the distance stored in a double type is not 0 but very small, will taking its reciprocal exceed the max value a double can represent? If yes, how do you check if the distance is small enough for bounding its reciprocal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This depends entirely on the precision you desire from your numbers, the maximum value in a double is very large, but suffers from tremendous rounding errors. If you need a precision of 1e-3 for instance you need at least 10 bits after the floating point, meaning you should not have any exponent greater than the number of bits in the mantissa minus 10, in the case of a double, that is 52 - 10 = 42, leaving you with a maximum of about 4e12 and a corresponding minimum of about 2.5e-13.

Answer (score 4):

Using `#include <limits>` you have

Small positive value = `std::numeric_limits<float>::denorm_min()`

Largest positive value = `std::numeric_limits<float>::max()`

Obviously this applies to other types as well.

See [numeric_limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/)

And no, the inverse of the smallest positive value does not equal the largest.

Comment: Thanks, can you try to answer my other questions please?

Answer (score 3):

Just looking for [numeric limits](http://cplusplus.com/reference/std/limits/numeric_limits/) information?

The link shows how to find the epsilon, denormalized min, etc., using the C++ Standard Library.  There is no equivalent for these in the C Standard Library.  You would need to compute them yourself (the Wikipedia article on "machine epsilon" gives an example)...

As for the algorithm, can't help you there, and this wasn't part of your original question, sorry.

Comment: Thanks, my questions are more than that.