# Min and max precision of a denormalized double?

Tags: floating-point, double, precision, ieee-754

What are the maximum and minimum precision of a denormalized 64 bit floating point number following IEEE 754-2008? That is, what's the precision of a double at 2^-1022 and 2^-1074 respectively?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185953/machine-precision-and-max-and-min-value-of-a-double-precision-type) is similar, but it does not care about the actual numbers.

Comment: It's not immediately clear that "precision of a double at 2^-1022" is a well-defined thing: I think it's reasonable to say that the IEEE 754-2008 binary64 format represents values in the binade (2^-1022, 2^-1021) with precision 53, and values in (2^-1023, 2^-1022) with precision 52 (and so on), but how you handle the endpoints is somewhat ambiguous. Did you have a particular definition of "precision" in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision of denormalized double precision floating point numbers gradually vanishes from 52 bits to 1 bit.

Hence, the mechanism is called *gradual underflow*.

Answer (score 0):

All denorms have the same precision, 52 bits with the least significant bit representing 2^-1074.

Comment: How can the precision be the same when the number of significant bits decreases? (Are we talking about the same "precision"?)

Comment: @FilipHaglund The precision of denormals is absolute, not relative. All bits of a denormal are "significant".

Comment: @Sneftel Leading 0s aren't significant, so the precision varies from 1 to 52 bits; 2^-1074 has one bit of precision.

Answer (score 0):

merely from trial and error, I've found a more intuitive and near-symmetric way to write out the smallest double-precision denormalized number

- **`2 ^ -1074`**

> ```
>     =    2^-4^+5 * 4^-5^+2
> ```

it's expressed with right-to-left precedence/associativity for the power operator `^` (aka "circumflex"), including the sign.

when they're grouped together unambiguously , it would be

> ```
>       2^-( 4^5 ) * 4^-( 5^2 )
> ```

The left-half is equivalent to

> ```
>       2 ** ( -1 * ( 4 ** 5 ) )
> ```

which is just another way of saying `2 ^ -1024`